Caused by android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException for Android 14
Although there are many problems similar to the question mentioned in the title, none of them work for Android 14. That's why I will take care to present my question with as clear sources as possible.
As far as Firebase Crashlytics shows, the relevant error is shown in line 166 of my pedometer service that I created for the Android 14 device.
Crash Report SS
Crash Report:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to create service com.packagename.stepcounter.StepCounterService: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.packagename/.stepcounter.StepCounterService
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:5111)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException
Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.packagename/.stepcounter.StepCounterService
android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel (ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:54)

android.app.Service.startForeground (Service.java:862)
com.packagename.stepcounter.StepCounterService.onCreate (StepCounterService.java:166)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:5098)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1103)


I share all the codes respectively.
Manifest:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_HEALTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.HIGH_SAMPLING_RATE_SENSORS"
        tools:ignore="HighSamplingRate" />


    <service
            android:name=".stepcounter.StepCounterService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="health"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />

Step Counter Service Helper (to turn on and off)
public class StepServiceHelper {
    public Activity activity;
    public StepCounterService mService;
    public static final String TAG = "StepCallback";
    public boolean mIsRunning;
    boolean mBound = false;

    public StepServiceHelper(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }



    private boolean isServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager =
                (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if ("com.packagename.stepcounter.StepCounterService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void startService() {
        if (!isServiceRunning()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] Start");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Please allow notifications from the application settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION);
                    } else {
                        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(activity, new Intent(activity, StepCounterService.class));
                    }
                } else {
                    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(activity, new Intent(activity, StepCounterService.class));
                }
            } else {
                activity.getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(activity, StepCounterService.class));
            }
        }
    }


    public void stopService() {
        if (isServiceRunning()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] stopService");
            activity.getApplicationContext().stopService(new Intent(activity, StepCounterService.class));
        }
    }

  }


StepCounterService (The line number where the error occurs is line 166.)

public class StepCounterService extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = "StepService";
    public SensorManager mSensorManager;
    public static final Integer NOTIFICATION_ID = 9;
    public NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    public NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private final IBinder binder = new StepBinder();
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    StepDetector mStepDetector;

    public class StepBinder extends Binder {
        public StepCounterService getService() {
            return StepCounterService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] onBind");
        return binder;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] unBind");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] reBind");
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] start");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void clearNotification() {
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] onCreate");

        Intent myintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);


        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.counter_channel))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setSilent(true)
                .setSound(null)
                .setForegroundServiceBehavior(NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0})
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.counter_channel), getString(R.string.counter_channel), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription(getString(R.string.counter_channel));
            channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0});
            channel.enableVibration(false);
            channel.setSound(null, null);
            channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build(), FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_HEALTH); // This is line 166
        } else {
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
 
        // The text on the notification will be updated
        updateNotification();
}


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "[SERVICE] onDestroy");
        unregisterDetector();
        clearNotification();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        if (!isServiceRunning() && SharedPreferencesReceiver.getStepServiceRun(getApplicationContext())) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                startForegroundService(new Intent(this, StepCounterService.class));
            } else {
                startService(new Intent(this, StepCounterService.class));
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager =
                (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if ("com.packagename.stepcounter.StepCounterService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



    private void updateNotification() {
        RemoteViews notificationLayout;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.step_notification_layout_collapsed);
        } else {
            notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.step_notification_layout);
        }

        notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.stepCount, String.valueOf(db_steps));
        notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.stepKcal, String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.1f", db_calories));

        mBuilder.setCustomContentView(notificationLayout);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            RemoteViews step_notification_layout_expanded = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.step_notification_layout_expanded);
            step_notification_layout_expanded.setTextViewText(R.id.adimsayisi, String.valueOf(db_steps));
            step_notification_layout_expanded.setTextViewText(R.id.gkcaltext, String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.1f", db_calories));
            mBuilder.setCustomBigContentView(step_notification_layout_expanded);
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build(), FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_HEALTH);
        } else {
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }



}

I added all the codes and necessary explanations. I don't have the slightest information about why and how the problem occurs. I encountered it once while testing my application, but even then I don't know how I did it. There was a problem for users with Android 14 operating system on Firebase
Additional info
I call it in the onStop method in MainActivity. I don't know if this is wrong
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("TAG_RES", "main_stop");
        if (SharedPreferencesHelper.getStepServiceRun(getApplicationContext())) {
            stepCallback.startService();
        } else {
            stepCallback.stopService();
        }
    }



When and how are you calling startService() on your helper? It feels like you are doing that at a point when foreground starts are not available to you (e.g., your UI is in the background).

@CommonsWare
is this a problem? I call it in several places. For example, in the onStop method in MainActivity:
    @Override     protected void onStop() {         super.onStop();         Log.d("TAG_RES", "main_stop");         if (SharedPreferencesHelper.getStepServiceRun(getApplicationContext())) {             stepCallback.startService();         } else {             stepCallback.stopService();         }     }

"is this a problem?" -- you cannot start a foreground service from the background on modern versions of Android.

@CommonsWare I put it in the onCreate method and now I will send a new update and observe it. So what does it have to do with line 166 where the error in Service is shown? Do I need to do anything here?
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build(), FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_HEALTH); // This is line 166

"Do I need to do anything here?" -- probably not.

@CommonsWare Hello, I added the service that I started in onStop to the onCreate method, but it still gives the same error.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build(), FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_HEALTH); // here166.line
    } else {
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }


Caused by android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException
Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service
